# How to copy and append mutiple string from a list into another list

Tags: python, list, loops

Lets say, i have a list below:

```
list1 = ['jenny', 'bob', 'dan']
```

I would like to copy each of item in the list1 into the second list to be like this:

```
list2 = [('jenny', 'bob'), ('bob','dan'),('dan','jenny')]

#This is my code:
list2=[]
for i in range(len(list2)):
    list2 += list1[i]

print(list2)
```

the poor thing is that my code could not even copy a word into the list2, but it is copying a char by char instead.

Comment: If your goal is to have all combinations of 2 there is already support for that in itertools

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations()` to get the combinations:

```
list1 = ['jenny', 'bob', 'dan']
list2 = list(itertools.combinations(list1, r=2))
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[('jenny', 'bob'), ('jenny', 'dan'), ('bob', 'dan')]
```

If you want to partner each with the next item (looping back if at the end of the loop), you can use modulo `%`:

```
list1 = ['jenny', 'bob', 'dan']
list2 = []
for i, name in enumerate(list1):
    name2 = list1[(i+1) % len(list1)]
    list2.append((name, name2))
```

Output:

```
[('jenny', 'bob'), ('bob','dan'),('dan','jenny')]
```

Comment: Use variable list1 don't write the list again

Comment: @azro OP is already having difficulties with a simple `for` loop, if the goal is to write the shortest code possible instead of being explicit so as to avoid confusion, I would write this in one line and not use `list1` as well

Comment: A variable is created to be used, I was talking about `list(itertools.combinations([list1, r=2))`.

Comment: @azro Point taken and I stand corrected. Answer updated.

Comment: @VictorE , how about if i add one more list > list3 to be list3 =  [‘John’,’Delly’,’San’,’Doe’]. I wish to get the expected output from the combinantion of list1 and list3: [('jenny', 'bob'), ('bob','dan'),('dan','John'),('John','Delly'),('Delly','San'),('San','Doe')] ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. `list2` is built with the i-th and (i+1)-th elements:

```
list1 = ['jenny', 'bob', 'dan']
list2 = [(el1, el2) for el1, el2 in zip(list1, list1[1:]+[list1[0]])]
```

output:

```
[('jenny', 'bob'), ('bob', 'dan'), ('dan', 'jenny')]
```

Comment: An answer without explanation values nothing. And this is not a race don't tell me you're doing it after ;)

Comment: @riccardo, thanks for the code. what the purpose of (el1, el2) before the for statement?